# When I use Chinese as URL parameter，it doesn't work with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, urllib

```
url='https://www.bing.com/search?q=你好&qs=n&form=QBLH&pq=你好&sc=2-0&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=8F0865226C'
urllib.request.urlopen(url)
```

Then console shows this:

[image]

Comment: Change your encoding. [Try](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276200/changing-default-encoding-of-python) this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to encode the double byte chars with quote from urllib.parse.

```
import urllib.request
from urllib.parse import quote

url='https://www.bing.com/search?q=%s&qs=n&form=QBLH&pq=%s&sc=2-0&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=8F0865226C'%(quote('你好'),quote('你好'))
urllib.request.urlopen(url)
```

you can read more from : [How to deal with unicode string in URL in python3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11818362/how-to-deal-with-unicode-string-in-url-in-python3)

Comment: OP is using Python 3 - strings are unicode and do not require the `u` prefix.

Comment: Didn't realise it is tagged as Python 3. I have removed the first part about the "u" prefix

Comment: Again. OP is using Python 3. `urllib.urlopen()` is from Python 2.

Comment: follow your tips,but console show that AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'timeout'